# Prisma: How can I implement a complex conditional query in Prisma?

Tags: sql, prisma

I have the following SQL query which I have to convert into a Prisma query but it seems that Prisma does not allow nested AND and OR query.How can the same be done?

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
WHERE (firstname LIKE '%Alex%' OR  firstname LIKE '%Sean%') 
AND (lastname LIKE '%Dennard%' OR lastname  LIKE '%Joy%') 
AND (age = 10) 
AND (middlename LIKE 'Ali%' AND middlename NOT LIKE 'Alish')
```

Comment: Lastname cannot be LIKE 2 different things at the same time, you are using an AND in this `AND (lastname LIKE '%Dennard%' AND lastname  LIKE '%Joy%')` So that should probably be an OR

Comment: _but it seems that Prisma does not allow nested AND and OR query_ What precisely makes you think that? Because it does not seem likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run this:

```js
await prisma.employee.findMany({
  where: {
    AND: [
      {
        OR: [
          { firstname: { contains: "Alex" } },
          { firstname: { contains: "Sean" } },
        ],
      },
      {
        OR: [
          { lastname: { contains: "Dennard" } },
          { lastname: { contains: "Joy" } },
        ],
      },
      {
        age: 10,
      },
      // ...
    ],
  },
});
```